# nested constructor. Why is it required?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

```
class Character(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y, hp):
        Entity.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.hp = hp
        self.items = []
```

`Character` is a child class of the parent class `Entity`. `Entity` class also has a `__init__` function. Why is there a need to write both the `__init__` functions? Why not only write the `__init__()` for the `Character` class, which would overwrite the `__init__()` for `Entity`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what happens in `Entity.__init__`! If (and *only if*) all it does is set `self.x` and `self.y`, you could do:

```
class Character(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y, hp):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.hp = hp
        self.items = []
```

But this is one line longer already, and if *anything else* other than setting arguments to instance attributes gets done in `Entity.__init__` (like, for example, `self.items = []` in `Character.__init__`) your `Character` may not work properly.

It is good practice to call the super-class's `__init__` method, to make sure that everything that needs to be done gets done.

You can make your code more general using `super`:

```
class Character(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y, hp):
        super(Character, self).__init__(x, y)
```

So that if you change what `Character` inherits from your `__init__` still works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but then you won't be calling the constructor of the superclass (`Entity`). In that case it's up to your constructor to make sure the object ends up in a consistent state.

The alternative is to call the constructor of the superclass and then perform some further actions that are needed for a `Character` instance. This means you'll already have an object in a consistent state (after the `Entity` constructor is finished) and you're only making further adjustments that are specific to `Character` objects.

Comment: \__init__ is not a constructor

Comment: @volcano: technically you're right although for practical purposes `__init__` is used to initialize the object (hence it serves a similar purpose as constructors in other languages).

Comment: constructors in other languages although allocate memory and return object reference

Comment: @volcano: that's true. In that sense `__init__` is more a method that simply runs by default after the object has been constructed.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there a need to write both the `__init__` functions?

There isn’t. You’re doing two completely different things here:

- You *define* `Character.__init__`, and
- You *call* `Entity.__init__`.

As you’ve noticed yourself, `Character`’s `__init__` method overrides `Entity`’s. So if you want to invoke that, you need to call it explicitly from within `Character`’s now.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what the classes are supposed to do.

If we suppose that the classes initiate their own stuff respectively, then you see that

- `Entity` inits its own attributes `x` and `y` and
- `Character` inits its additional attributes `hp` and `items`.

You could put the initialization of `x` and `y` to `Character` as well, but then what about `Entity` itself and tis other child classes?

Answer (score 0):

Without adding to what is already said above - it is a common mistake to call __init__ method a constructor - **but it is not**!
Constructor is a __new__ method, and is seldom used.
Python documentation is a little bit cryptic on the issue - [see here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__), but it never calls it constructor directly. Why? Constructor - in the standard OOP terminology, creates class instance - object - and returns it. __init__ simply **does not do it**!