# 2 approaches for searching for something in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

While looking for something inside a list:  I understand that it can be done either by (a) traversing the list using the for loop (or while loop) or (b) using the if something in list_1  statement. I tried both approaches for really big lists(1 million elements), and searched through them using both the approaches above for something that was not in the list. The first approach took 0.57 seconds and the second approach 0.21. These times were obtained repeatedly. 
If the second method using the if something in list_1 approach doesn't use list traversal how does it search for something in the list ?

Comment: -1 for no research effort and being unable to try this before posting.

Comment: -1 for asking just after this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117371/nested-constructor-why-is-it-required

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if all your `__init__` does is invoke the base class `__init__` you can remove your override altogether, and save yourself the extra stack push.